# selenium temple wallet click

Tags: python, selenium

**I want to click the password field using selenium**.

but I am not able to find the button selector.

this is the link of the object.

https://objkt.com/asset/hicetnunc/317305

the code I am using to get there.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver.get("https://objkt.com/asset/hicetnunc/317305")
buy_button_xpath = "//button[@class='action-button buy mb-20']"
buy_button_selector = driver.find_element_by_xpath(buy_button_xpath)

buy_button_selector.click()
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error you get. Check if its in an `iframe`.

Comment: When I manually click on buy 3 for t2 I got this `Something went wrong, please try again!`

Comment: Did my answer resolved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should wait for element presence and then scroll the element into the view. Something like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver.get("https://objkt.com/asset/hicetnunc/317305")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)
buy_button_xpath = "//button[@class='action-button buy mb-20']"
buy_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, buy_button_xpath)))
actions.move_to_element(buy_button).perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
buy_button.click()
```

Comment: This is not going to solve the problem. You have to stitch the window.

Comment: What do you mean?